# How to modify GET request size (IIS Express)

Tags: rest, express, iis, get, iis-express

I have coded a web application that runs on IIS Express. I want to send large data set to server(over 4MB) and get response. (I have implemented this as a REST service).

When i tried ,i realize that I can  only have 311bytes long URL. 
So how can i change that?

as i know IE allows 2083 length  URL as  default. and there should be a way to configure IIS express via web.config or applicationhost.config right?

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an http post verb to send the data, instead of trying to send it encoded in the URL as a GET. In straight HTML, this would involve having  a form tag with a submit button.  What framework are you coding this in? (asp.net, mvc, php, etc?)

Comment: I am using asp.net (with c# and IIS express) , my function is like [ Dictionary(Key, Value) GetData(Ilist i_dataset) ], where i want to send set of data to server and get response. ( I use serialization). How can i do that? Tahank you!!

Comment: Check out the JQuery Ajax command, this is probably the best way to consume a restful service, and you can easily make it do an http post  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/    if you are expecting to send more than 4mb of data in a single request,  you will need to modify the web.config file of your service, the maxRequestLength attribute of the httpRuntime tag is by default set to limit uploads to 4096k.

Comment: Thank you for the response!! I am using IIS Express, not IIS for my web application. I changed <httpruntime> property in my web.config already, but there is no use, what ever the size i set it sends only 311 bytes. I think this is a issue with IIS Express, I just want to know how to fix that.  Due to  nature of the project, i cant switch to IIS or use  another library. Thank you!